# Can't migrate Sqllite to mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have successfully installed mysqlclient in my django project folder.

prakash@prakash-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY:~/projects/MasterQuote$ pip3 install mysqlclient

Output :

Collecting mysqlclient

Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.12

DATABASE SETTINGS :

```
DATABASES = {
         'default' :{
             'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             'NAME'  :'MasterQuote',
             'USER'  : 'root',
             'PASSWORD' : 'root',
             'HOST' : 'localhost',
             'PORT' : ''
         }
}
```

But i try to migrate this error occured

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/home/prakash/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: share `settings.py` file

Comment: Are you using virtual environment? If yes, did you activated?. Share database settings also.

Comment: ohh i forget to activate virtual evironment

Comment: now I used virtual environment  but the error still there     my databse settings:DATABASES = {
         'default' :{
             'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             'NAME'  :'MasterQuote',
             'USER'  : 'root',
             'PASSWORD' : 'root',
             'HOST' : 'localhost',
             'PORT' : ''
         }
}

Answer (score 0):

First activate the virtual environment and then do,

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: i activate virtual environment but no improvement

Comment: Now same error or different? What is the error you are getting while runserver?

Comment: Yes Same error was occured. I am getting same error in runserver also

Comment: can you check whether pip freeze is showing mysqlclient installed? and check whether you are able to connect to db with out django.

Comment: pip freeze shows mysqlclient and also i checked database connection without django both are works well